# Editing data coming from backend and the then again save it back - ios 7

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, uilabel, appdelegate, nsjsonserialization

Here am showing the json response in one label, next to label edit button, if you click the edit button,it goes to the next controller having one textfield, here am showing the same label value in the previous controller in textfield, am changing the text now and going back to first controller, here the data is not changing it showing the same json response.I have tried by saving the value in app delegate,but its not working, please share some ideas.

```
 nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[[jsonData valueForKey:@"demo"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"first_name"],
```

above is the code to show the data in uilabel in firstviewcontroler.

```
   if ([firstnameField.text  isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",            [app.IndividualData valueForKey:@"first_name"] ]])
{
    //do nothing
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",firstnameField.text);
    [app.patientData setValue:firstnameField.text forKey:@"firstname"];
}
```

above is the code in second viewcontroller.

P.S. In viewdidLoad am parsing the json data.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Please show the code you use for saving and for reloading data in the first controller.

Comment: @PhillipMills : I have edited the question, please check.

Comment: If you're saving the modified data as `app.patientData`, when do you attempt to display that?

Comment: while going back to the first viewcontroller, modified data should be shown in label .

Comment: The question is, what code do you have that you think would **cause** the modified data to be shown?  If you have it in `app.patientData`, you have to read it back from there, right?